# How to copy a specific portion of text file to a specific cell in excel worksheet with python openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl

## open the specific output file 

with open('/Users/bekir/Desktop/Python_project/Output/r391.txt') as
wb:
    lines = wb.read().splitlines()

## find tht from output file

for line in lines[8400:8480]:
    if line.startswith('       top-water-inlet temp       ='):
        THT = line.split('=',1)[-1].strip()[0:6]

for line in lines[1:30]:
    if line.startswith('  Geometry file :'):
        run_number = line.split(':',1)[-1].strip()[0:4]

## write THT into a specific cell of excel worksheet      

file_path  = '/Users/bekir/Desktop/deneme.xlsx'
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
ws = xfile['Sheet3']

# have to start range from 1 since excel cell offset starts at 1
for i in range(1,100):
    cell = 'C' + str(i)

    if ws[cell].value == run_number:
        ws['J' + str(i)] = THT
        break

xfile.save(file_path)
```

Hi ,

I could find a specific poriton of text file but I couldn't copy into a specific cell of excel worksheet with openpyxl (python2.7). Program has to match `run_number` in the worksheet (already written in the worksheet) and write `THT` value into the coordinate ('J' column &`run number`s row). I couldn't write the second part of code. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_path  = '/Users/bekir/Documents/deneme.xlsx'
xfile = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
ws = xfile['sayfa3']

# have to start range from 1 since excel cell offset starts at 1
for i in range(1,100):
    cell = 'D' + str(i)

    if ws[cell].value == run_number:
        ws['D' + str(i)] = THT
        break

xfile.save(file_path)
```

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/worksheet.py:310: UserWarning: Unknown extension is not supported and will be removed
  warn(msg) .                 @Alex        Why I get this message?

Comment: @BekirAydin Please see my updated code as this will work. I properly tested this with no issues.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ Alex!! It is working perfectly after small corrections. I edited the code at the top.